# How to Handle `@WHEN` unsatisfied condition in `cucumber`?

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, language-features, cucumber-junit

In my case I used cucumber with Junit and in `@WHEN` i used logic for test.When my test is satisfied then my code goes to `@THEN`. But when my code is unsatisfied i use `org.Junit.Assert.fail()` to Fails a test with no message but I got following log error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
  at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
  at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:95)
  at com.abcfinancial.bdd.cucumber.serenity.cucumberstep.BusinessSignUp.validateTheProvidedFields(BusinessSignUp.java:66)
  at ✽.firstname is vikas lastName is jindal password is 1234576 email is bravo@asd.com organization name is abc location name is BananaMans Land Location Location address1 is 123 Main Rd address2 is Near XYZ  city is  Pizzaburg state is Ohio country is United States zipcode is 53421  org email address is vikas@gmail.com(src/test/resources/features/businesssignup/01business_sign_up.feature:8)
```

But i don't want `at ✽.firstname is vikas lastName is jindal password is 1234576 email is bravo@asd.com organization name is abc location name is BananaMans Land Location Location address1 is 123 Main Rd address2 is Near XYZ  city is  Pizzaburg state is Ohio country is United States zipcode is 53421  org email address is vikas@gmail.com(src/test/resources/features/businesssignup/01business_sign_up.feature:8)` line in Error.

my java class is:

```
public class BusinessSignUp {
private static final Logger applicationLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ApplicationLogger");

GlobalBeans signUpDomaindomain = null;
String threadId = String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId());
Map<String, GlobalBeans> refIdMap = GlobalRefIdMap.getRefIdMapInstance().getRefIdMap();

@Steps
BusinessSignUpSerenity businessSignUpSteps;

@Given("^Tester Name is (.*)$")
public void givenBaseUri(String tester) {
    applicationLogger.info("Tester Name is {}", tester);

}

@When("^firstname is (.*) lastName is (.*) password is (.*) email is (.*) organization name is (.*) location name" +
        " is (.*) Location address1 is (.*) address2 is (.*)  city is  (.*) state is (.*) country is (.*) zipcode" +
        " is (.*)  org email address is (.*)$")
public void validateTheProvidedFields(String firstName, String lastName, String password, String email, String
        orgName, String organizationLocationName, String organizationLocationAddress1, String
                                              organizationLocationAddress2, String organizationLocationCity,
                                      String organizationLocationState, String
                                              organizationLocationCountry, String organizationLocationZip, String
                                              orgEmail) {
    try {
        if (refIdMap.size() == 0) {
            refIdMap = Utility.setBusinessSignupDomain(threadId, firstName, lastName, password, email, orgName,
                    organizationLocationName, organizationLocationAddress1, organizationLocationAddress2,
                    organizationLocationCity, organizationLocationState, organizationLocationCountry,
                    organizationLocationZip, orgEmail);
        }
        signUpDomaindomain = refIdMap.get(threadId);
        applicationLogger.info("Printing domain in BusinessSignUp with  {}", signUpDomaindomain);
        businessSignUpSteps.doSignup(signUpDomaindomain, refIdMap);


    } catch (Exception exception) {
        applicationLogger.error("Printing exception detail {}", exception.getMessage());
        exception.printStackTrace();
        Assert.fail();
    }

}

@Then("^SignUp is(.*)$")
public void success(String message) {
    if (AppConstants.success_message.equals(message.trim())) {
        applicationLogger.info("***** SignUp is : {} *****", message);
    } else {
        applicationLogger.info("***** SignUp is : {} *****", AppConstants.unsuccessful_message);
    }
  }

}
```

In above class i am using SignUp code where i used feature file as follows:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11K0I-XYE6BzIrzbrAzk8odfaze-S5oRE?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

In the latest **cucumber version 2.4.0**, the class which adds the last stacktrace line about the feature file is from the `cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch` class. The exact method is - `removeFrameworkFramesAndAppendStepLocation()`. This basically appends the `stacktrace` with the relevant line from the feature file (Object of `StackTraceElement` class). You will need to look at the call from `runStep()` method.

Even if you change this, the code for this class is going to be changed pretty extensively in the next release.